# Cannot set salesorder to fulfilled CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I have written the following code for order fulfillment in crm 2013.

```
FulfillSalesOrderRequest req = new FulfillSalesOrderRequest();
req.OrderClose = new Entity();
req.OrderClose.LogicalName = "salesorder";
req.OrderClose.Id = pSalesOrderId;
OptionSetValue o = new OptionSetValue();
o.Value = 100001;
req.Status = o;
FulfillSalesOrderResponse resp = (FulfillSalesOrderResponse)_service.Execute(req);
```

But Order is not getting fulfilled.

Please help me if anything i am missing ?

Comment: An "unexpected error" in my experience means that the program you're using failed in a way that isn't correctable by the user. I'd recommend getting in touch with the developers.

Comment: please be more specific on the error (message, stacktrace, ...)

Comment: No exception or error comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OrderClose` property is an `orderclose`, not a `salesorder`. In addition you need to set the `SalesOrderId` property

try with this code (assuming your status value is valid)

```
FulfillSalesOrderRequest req = new FulfillSalesOrderRequest();

req.OrderClose = new Entity("orderclose");
req.OrderClose["salesorderid"] = new EntityReference("salesorder", pSalesOrderId);
req.Status = new OptionSetValue(100001);

FulfillSalesOrderResponse resp = (FulfillSalesOrderResponse)_service.Execute(req);
```

Comment: req.OrderClose.SalesOrderId is not available. I am getting req.OrderClose.Id and req.OrderClose.LogicalName

Comment: Can i write this line : req.OrderClose.Id = new Guid(new EntityReference("salesorder", pSalesOrderId).ToString());

Comment: I am getting this error : The entity cannot be updated because it is read-only.

Comment: Previous status is "SUBMITTED". But it is CRM's process that Order will get ACTIVE after that SUBMIT and after that it goes to FULFILLED state.

Comment: strange, I checked and from submitted you can fulfill the order. 100001 is "Complete", it should work. Right now I can't test the code, but I will do tomorrow. I suggest you to try with a brand new order record

Comment: just tested, the code works, a submitted order is made to complete.

Comment: do you have checked that with submitted Order ?

Comment: yes, I created an order, change its status to submitted first (with an ondemand workflow) and after ran the code, the order became fulfilled

Comment: are you sure for that ? because i am taking any order with statecode 1 (submitted) giving me an error "entity is readonly".

Comment: One noticeable thing is that because of this code my "SetStateDynamicEntity"  plugins are not calling. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I'm sure about that, and you can start a new crm online trial and test it. If you have other codes connected to sales order (like a plugin) it can stop the code to be executed in some cases (like an exception)

Comment: Your code is working fine, but in my case i have submit order from javascript and after that i am calling a workflow which fulfill that order and that creates the problem of 'The entity cannot be updated because it is read-only.'. I haven't identified the problem yet but thanks for your help .!!!